# Regex for alphanumeric and some Special Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex -

Requirement -

1) one alphabets compulsory

2) one number compulsory

and some special characters are also allowed its not compulsory.

special characters - `` [-!$^&*()_|~=`{}[]:/<>?,.@#] ``

I have tried

```
/((^\S*[0-9]+\S*[a-z]+\S*)|(^\S*[a-z]+\S*[0-9]+\S*))+$/i
```

but how to restrict that with given special characters only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookahead:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)(?=.*[-!$^&*()_|~=`{}\[\]:/<>?,.@#]+)[-\w!$^&*()|~=`{}\[\]:/<>?,.@#]+$/
```

If special char are not compulsory:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)[-\w!$^&*()|~=`{}\[\]:/<>?,.@#]+$/
```

Comment: Special characters are not compulsory.